# Model Counting for Sum of Conjunctive Formulas

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

### Problem:

Let $X=\{x_1, ..., x_N \}$ be a set of binary variables. Each variable can be assigned to either $0$ or $1$ so there are $2^N$ possible assignments.

**Input:** We are given a positive integer $C$ and a set of binary functions $F=\{f_1,...,f_M\}$ where each function is defined as a simple conjunction of some subset of $X$. That is, each $f_i \in F$ is defined as $f_i(X) := \prod_{x \in X'}x$ for some $X' \subseteq X$.

**Output:** The number of assignments to variables in $X$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^M f_i(X) = C$.

### Question:

Do you know of a polynomial-time algorithm that solves this problem for a bounded value of $C$?

Any ideas or pointers to references would also be greatly appreciated.

It is OK if the complexity is bounded with respect to e.g. some constant $D$ which could be the maximum size of $X'$, that is, the maximum number of variables in the product of any function $f_i \in F$.

### Observations:

When $|X'|=1$, that is, when each function $f_i \in F$ can only have one variable, then the problem can be reduced to the counting version of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and can be solved in $\mathcal{O}(N\cdot C)$ time using an modified version of a [dynamic programming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) for solving subset sum.

Comment: Are the $X_i'$ sets distinct?

Comment: In the general case, no. And given the practical application I have for this problem, I don't think the case where they are distinct is interesting. Also, $M$ is usually much larger than $N$.

Comment: And do you really want just the count or the actual assignments?

Comment: Just the count, the set of assignments is exponential in size I think ;)

Comment: What is the practical application?

Comment: It's a bit of a mouth-full but here goes: Tracking the provenance information of a dataset that is the result of a series of data-transformation operators. Operators correspond to variables. Setting $x_i=0$ turns the operator off. Each tuple in the output dataset is assigned a polynomial that is constructed based on operators that were applied to it. I'm interested in finding the number of on/off arrangements of operators that result in a dataset of a specific size $C$.